# COBOL CAN'T WRITE RECORDS IN MY NOTEPAD FILES

Tags: cobol

I just want to know why i can't see my records on my Notepad files, is there something wrong in my code? I created my Notepad files into this path: "C:\Users\jamal.eclipse\MicroFocus\Student-Record.txt". When I run the code, it asks me the student number, the student tuition owed and the student name but can't see it in my Notepad files. Here's my code:

```
       program-id. Project as "Project".
       environment division.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT STUDENT-FILE-IN
           ASSIGN TO 
           "C:\Users\jamal\.eclipse\MicroFocus\Student-Record.txt"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       configuration section.

       data division.
       FILE Section.
       FD STUDENT-FILE-IN.
       01 STUDENT-RECORD-OUT PIC X(52).
       working-storage section.
       01 STUDENT-RECORD-IN.
         05 STUDENT-NUMBER PIC 9(6).
         05 TUITION-OWED PIC 9(6).
         05 STUDENT-NAME PIC X(40).
         
       01 PROMPT-MESSAGES-RESPONSES.
         05 RECORD-Y-N PIC X(41) VALUE 
         "Do you have record ? Y or N: ".
         05 RESPONSE PIC X(1).
         05 STUDENT-NUMBER-OUT PIC X(24) VALUE 
         "Enter the Student Number: ".
         05 TUITION-OWED-OUT PIC X(22) VALUE 
         "Enter the tuition owed: ".
         05 STUDENT-NAME-OUT PIC X(22) VALUE 
         "Enter your Student Name: ".
         
         
         
         
      

       procedure division.
           CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
           PERFORM STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
           PERFORM CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD
           UNTIL RESPONSE="N" or "n".
           PERFORM T-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
           
    
       STOP RUN.
           
       STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
           PERFORM OPEN-RECORD.
           PERFORM PROMPT-USER.
       
       CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.
           PERFORM ENTER-STUDENT-DATA.
           PERFORM WRITE-STUDENT-RECORD.
           PERFORM PROMPT-USER.
       
       T-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
           PERFORM CLS-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.
       
       OPEN-RECORD.
           OPEN OUTPUT STUDENT-FILE-IN.
       
       PROMPT-USER.
           DISPLAY RECORD-Y-N.
           ACCEPT RESPONSE.
       
       ENTER-STUDENT-DATA.
           DISPLAY STUDENT-NUMBER-OUT.
           ACCEPT STUDENT-NUMBER.
           DISPLAY TUITION-OWED-OUT.
           ACCEPT TUITION-OWED.
           DISPLAY STUDENT-NAME-OUT
           ACCEPT STUDENT-NAME.
       
       WRITE-STUDENT-RECORD.
           MOVE STUDENT-RECORD-IN TO STUDENT-RECORD-OUT.
           WRITE STUDENT-RECORD-OUT.
       
       CLS-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.
           CLOSE STUDENT-FILE-IN.
           
             
           

       end program Project.
```

I'm a beginner to Cobol, thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I highly suggest to recheck your program logic and namings CREATE-.. only does CLOSE, OPEN-RECORD creates the FILE, ....
Additional hint: `CONFIGURATION SECTION` is at the wrong place - but as you don't need it just delete that line completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program, i made some changes , i hope that will help you

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. project.
   environment division.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT STUDENT-FILE-IN
       ASSIGN TO  "C:\Users\jamal\.eclipse\MicroFocus\Student-Record.txt"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
   configuration section.

   data division.
   FILE Section.
   FD STUDENT-FILE-IN.
   01 STUDENT-RECORD-OUT PIC X(52).
   working-storage section.
   01 STUDENT-RECORD-IN.
     05 STUDENT-NUMBER PIC 9(6).
     05 TUITION-OWED PIC 9(6).
     05 STUDENT-NAME PIC X(40).
     
   01 PROMPT-MESSAGES-RESPONSES.
     05 RECORD-Y-N PIC X(41) VALUE 
     "Do you have record ? Y or N: ".
     05 RESPONSE PIC X(1).
     05 STUDENT-NUMBER-OUT PIC X(20) VALUE "Enter Student Number".
     05 TUITION-OWED-OUT PIC X(20) VALUE "Enter tuition owed:".
     05 STUDENT-NAME-OUT PIC X(20) VALUE "Enter Student Name:".
     
       procedure division.
       OPEN OUTPUT STUDENT-FILE-IN.
       PERFORM PROMPT-USER.
       PERFORM CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD
       UNTIL RESPONSE="N" or "n".
       PERFORM T-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
       
   CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.
       PERFORM ENTER-STUDENT-DATA.
       PERFORM WRITE-STUDENT-RECORD.
       PERFORM PROMPT-USER.
   
   T-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD-FILE.
       PERFORM CLS-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.     
   PROMPT-USER.
       DISPLAY RECORD-Y-N.
       ACCEPT RESPONSE.
   
   ENTER-STUDENT-DATA.
       DISPLAY STUDENT-NUMBER-OUT.
       ACCEPT STUDENT-NUMBER.
       DISPLAY TUITION-OWED-OUT.
       ACCEPT TUITION-OWED.
       DISPLAY STUDENT-NAME-OUT
       ACCEPT STUDENT-NAME.
   
   WRITE-STUDENT-RECORD.
       MOVE STUDENT-RECORD-IN TO STUDENT-RECORD-OUT.
       WRITE STUDENT-RECORD-OUT.
   
   CLS-CREATE-STUDENT-RECORD.
       CLOSE STUDENT-FILE-IN
       STOP RUN.
```

Comment: While this is the accepted answer it does not match the Stackoverflow Q+A style (but the style of a coding site) - can you please add an "answer" in there (what needed to be changed and  why)?